# Using a child controller from another module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've defined a module and made it the main module for my app using the ng-app directive. I added two controllers to the main app using angular.module('myApp').controller(). One of those controllers has page wide scope whereas the other controller is a child controller.

What I'm now trying to do is include a controller that belongs to another module (not the main myApp module), but I can't figure it out. I do not want to globally namespace controllers.

Anyone know how to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myApp.mainController'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var app, module;

      //create two modules, one of which will be used for the app base
      app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      module = angular.module('otherModule', []);

      //create main controller for main app
      app.controller('myApp.mainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.content = 'App main controller content';
      });

      //create child controller for main app
      app.controller('myApp.subController', function($scope) {
        $scope.content = 'App sub controller content';
      });

      //create a controller for the other module
      module.controller('othermodule.controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.content = 'Other module controller content';
      });
    });


  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- output content from main controller from main module: myApp -->
  {{content}}

  <!-- specify use of main module's child controller and output its content -->
  <div data-ng-controller='myApp.subController'>
    {{content}}
  </div>

  <!-- NOT WORKING - ideally should output content from the other module's controller -->
  <div data-ng-controller='othermodule.controller'>
    {{content}}
  </div>

  <!-- load angular library -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code outputs the following with a JavaScript error essentially saying that the othermodule.controller controller was not found.

> App main controller content
>
> App sub controller content
>
> {{content}}

Exact Error:

```
> Error: Argument 'othermodule.controller' is not a function, got
> undefined
> assertArg@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:1005
> assertArgFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:1016
> @http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:4740
> applyDirectivesToNode/nodeLinkFn/<@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:4322
> forEach@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:140
> nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:4307
> compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:3953
> compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:3956
> nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:4338
> compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:3953
> publicLinkFn@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:3858
> bootstrap/</<@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:964
> Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:7993
> Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:8073
> bootstrap/<@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:962
> invoke@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:2843
> bootstrap@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:961
> angularInit@http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:936
> @http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js:14729
> b.Callbacks/c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3
> b.Callbacks/p.fireWith@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3
> .ready@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3
> H@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3
> 
> http://localhost/sandbox/angular/apptemplate/lib/angular/angular.js
> Line 5687
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you have done currently is "declared" two modules `app` and `module`.

When angular bootstraps, you have asked it to bootstrap with `app`. So now your application bootstraps with `app` but the `app` has no reference to your other module ( which is `module`! ).

So, you will have to either bootstrap your application with `app` and specify a dependency on `module` or bootstrap your application with a totally new module and specify a dependency on `app` and `module`.

This is how you define a dependency

```
angular.module('app',['module']);
```

If you want to create a totally new module and specify both as dependencies

```
angular.module('myApp',['app','module'])
```

**Note :**  if you create a totally new module, you will have to bootstrap your angular application with this new module..

```
<html ng-app="myApp"...
```

Comment: That makes 100% sense. Thank you.